# Oracle How to return a string in a particular format

Tags: oracle

I have one requirement where i want to return output in a particular format based on one column(Idx). In one column we have date range based on that loop should execute.

```
drop table t_table_test;
create table t_table_test ( ID NUMBER, NM VARCHAR2(4000), VAL VARCHAR2(4000), IDX NUMBER);
select * from t_table_test;
INSERT INTO t_table_test VALUES (1,'CNTRY', 'USA',1);
INSERT INTO t_table_test VALUES (1,'DT', '2017-01-01,2017-01-02',2);
INSERT INTO t_table_test VALUES (1,'PART', 'NA',3);
```

If Input is below

```
ID NM            VAL                   IDX
1   CNTRY       USA                   1
1   DT        2017-01-01,2017-01-02   2
1   PART        NA                    3
```

Output should be this will be based on IDX column

```
CNTRY:USA,DT:2017-01-01,PART:NA?CNTRY:USA,DT:2017-01-02,PART:NA
```

I/P

```
ID NM       VAL                   IDX
1   DT        2017-01-01,2017-01-02 1
1   CNTRY       USA                   2
1   PART        NA                    3

 DT:2017-01-01,CNTRY:USA,PART:NA?DT:2017-01-02,CNTRY:USA,PART:NA
```

DELETE FROM t_table_test WHERE idx=3; 
commit;
O/P     DT:2017-01-01,CNTRY:USA?DT:2017-01-02,CNTRY:USA
DELETE FROM t_table_test WHERE idx=1; 
commit;
O/P     DT:2017-01-01?DT:2017-01-02
Need query which work in all above cases .

Comment: Just to be clear: what would happen if the VAL column in more than one record will contain multiple values? For instance, if NM=CNTRY and VALUE=USA,CANADA and IDX=1, as well as NM=DT and VAL=2017-01-01,2017-01-02 and IDX=2?

Comment: Thanks multiple values will be there only for DT no other column have multiple entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this:

```
select rtrim(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,val||'?')).EXTRACT('//text()'),',') from (
with dates as (SELECT distinct NM||':'||trim(regexp_substr(val, '[^,]+', 1, level)) val 
from t_table_test where nm='DT' CONNECT BY instr(val, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0),
parts as (select NM||':'||VAL val FROM t_table_test where nm='PART')
SELECT NM||':'||t.VAL||','||d.VAL||','||p.val val from t_table_test t, dates d, parts p 
where NM='CNTRY');
```

It does rely on the names being fixed - having only DT being a comma separated list of values, for instance - but I think it might help you format your results. You can use this as a basis for building many similar formatting solutions.

Comment: Actually issue here is NM value is not fixed. it can be anything and DT is range it can be for 3 days 01-01-2017,02-01-2017,03-01-2017 also

Comment: having DT being more than two values is not a problem with the given solution. 
Having NM being other values than CNTRY and PART is also OK - can you know the values, or are you selecting from a completely unknown source?

Comment: yes you are right DT more value is not an issue here. requirement is sometime i have only one column for that ID . if one column then return col_NM:COL_VL. if more than one vlaue then use IDX column and which is having first index should be first and then next and so on.

Comment: yes you are right DT more value is not an issue here. requirement is sometime i have only one column for that ID . if one column then return col_NM:COL_VL. if more than one vlaue then use IDX column and which is having first index should be first and then next and so on. e.g. Output can  CNTRY:USA,DT:2017-01-01,PART:NA?CNTRY:USA,DT:2017-01-02,PART:NA or CNTRY:USA or CNTRY:USA,PART:NA or DT:2017-01-01:2017-01-02 and so on based on input we have.

Comment: Wow. OK, that requires a much more robust solution. so basically we are gathering an unknown number of records?

Comment: yes correct. sometime we will get 3 sometime 4 sometime 1. Actually there are two types of parameters 1 normal and 2nd date. Date will be mostly range so used as loop whereas others will be only name value pair. Position will be decided by idx column

Comment: If it's a small range of possibilities - up to 4 extra key-pair values that may be there and maybe not, let's say - I would still use the solution I shown above and just add another few with clauses. In small scale, that's not a big deal. If we're talking about dozens of options for key-pair values, this solution will not do - and I have no better suggestion.

Comment: Problem here is name is not fixed. e.g. parts as (select NM||':'||VAL val FROM t_table_test where nm='PART' so in NM we will have any values

Comment: Not having any values is no big deal. You'll just have no values in the row, it will not prevent it from displaying a result.

Comment: This is failing in SELECT NM||':'||t.VAL||','||d.VAL||','||p.val val from t_table_test t, dates d, parts p 
where NM='CNTRY because in parts we have no values so null is returning . do we use outer join here to join these

Comment: It could work. You're the most qualified person to test out variations on the solution, as you have the various inputs. If you want help with specific end-cases, could you please edit the question to add them in?

Comment: Thanks and Editing and added 2 more conditions (deletes) so same query should work in all scenarios.

Comment: fantastic. Any chance I can convince you to accept my answer?